# iphone have to hit back twice to get out of view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have numerous buttons that go to different views on my main page and they all work the same way - they go the view and the area for the back button has the text of the title of the main page.

Then on one view, it says "Back".  When you click "Back" - the view stays the same but the back button text changes to the same as the rest with "[title of the main page]".  So now when a user goes to this view they have to hit the back button twice to get back to the original page - what could cause that?

Comment: What does the code look like where you do pushViewController:? What does it look like where you do popViewController: (or whatever variant thereof)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using navigation based there will be back button on it with rootview contrller  class name on it...
this is for the popview controlller